# How to use IHttpClientAsyncLogger for logging http request/response details?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

In My Worker application, I need to log all outgoing requests and incoming responses. I found that there is an `IHttpClientAsyncLogger` that can add logging functionality in desired httpclient. So, I implemented the `IHttpClientAsyncLogger` interface like this:

```
public class HttpClientLogger : IHttpClientAsyncLogger
{
    private readonly ILogger<HttpClientLogger> _logger;
    public HttpClientLogger(ILogger<HttpClientLogger> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _logger.LogInformation("httpclient logger initiated");
    }
    public object? LogRequestStart(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("My logger hit on : {function}", nameof(LogRequestStart));
        return request;
    }

    public void LogRequestStop(object? context, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response, TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("My logger hit on : {function}", nameof(LogRequestStop));
    }

    public void LogRequestFailed(object? context, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage? response, Exception exception,
        TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("My logger hit on : {function}", nameof(LogRequestFailedAsync));
    }

    public ValueTask<object?> LogRequestStartAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("My logger hit on : {function}", nameof(LogRequestStartAsync));
        return ValueTask.FromResult<object?>(request);
    }

    public ValueTask LogRequestStopAsync(object? context, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage response,
        TimeSpan elapsed, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("My logger hit on : {function}", nameof(LogRequestStopAsync));
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public ValueTask LogRequestFailedAsync(object? context, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage? response,
        Exception exception, TimeSpan elapsed, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("My logger hit on : {function}", nameof(LogRequestFailedAsync));
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and then register it as below in my service collection in program.cs:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging((context, loggingBuilder) =>
    {
        var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration).CreateLogger();
        loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(logger);
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
 services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient", client =>
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150);
            }).RemoveAllLoggers()
            .AddLogger<HttpClientLogger>().AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
};
```

but when my client composes the HTTP request and receives the response none of the logging methods will be called.

How should I use the HTTP client logging infrastructure?

**Update:**

I Checked the "System.Net.Http.HttpClient" logging filter and also Implementing the `IHttpClientLogger` but no change in the final result.

Also, it is useful to mention that according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.http.logging.ihttpclientasynclogger?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0#remarks) documentation the sync methods are called in sync `Send` method of the HttpMessageHandler and async methods are called by `SendAsync` method.

Comment: Have you set the log level for HttpClient? Something like this: `"System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Debug"`

Comment: Yes, but no change ib result

Comment: Have you tried to implement the `IHttpClientLogger` interface instead?

Comment: It might worth to check this GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77312 especially section 3.

Comment: So, I tested the git hub's hint but there result is same :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It was my mistake that I was registering my HttpClientFactory using this code:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient("MyHttpClient", client =>
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(150);
            }).RemoveAllLoggers()
            .AddLogger<HttpClientLogger>().AddPolicyHandler(GetRetryPolicy());
```

but I was instantiating my `HttpClient` using this code:

```
var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("MyClient");
```